# Display recent posts based on their category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, categories, posts

I use a template that generates thumbnails on the content.php page like so:

```
<article <?php post_class('single-entry clearfix'); ?>>  
<?php
// Test if post has a featured image
if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    // Get resize and show featured image : refer to functions/img_defaults.php for default values
    $wpex_entry_img = aq_resize( wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' ),  wpex_img( 'blog_entry_width' ), wpex_img( 'blog_entry_height' ), wpex_img( 'blog_entry_crop' ) );
?>
    <div class="single-entry-thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $wpex_entry_img; ?>" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" /></a>
    </div><!-- /single-entry-thumbnail -->
<?php } ?>
<div class="entry-text clearfix">
    <header>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </header>
</div><!-- /entry-text -->
```

I am just starting with Wordpress and php and I want to add a parameter to this so only posts with category 'showcase' i.e. will show up. Anyone an idea?

Comment: You'll want to add an argument to the post query, which is happening above or before the code you've shared. Can you find any relevant `query_posts`, `WP_Query`, or `get_posts` to paste here?

Comment: Thanks @crowjonah for looking into it. That's the problem I ran into. This code seems to differ from the 'typical' WP loop. There are no such parameters in this or other .php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in_category() function to test that post belongs to it.

```
if ( in_category( 'showcase' ) ) {
    ...
}
```

in_category() docs - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

Comment: Yes, this code must be inside The Loop and surround <article> tag.

Comment: Placing this line of code surrounding the <article> tag did not work. I ended up adding the code **inside** the article tag and it works like a charm! Thank you very much @Vladimir! Would this work with **tags** as well? To show only articles with a certain tag?

Comment: Yes, this code would work with tags. But you should use has_term (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function instead of in_category.